# Call contract function multiple times with arguments from functions results

Tags: smartcontracts, web3py, bsc

I'm working on web3.py project where I need to call contract functions multiple times to retrieve data on users/wallets. When I call contract.functions

```
user_info = contract.functions.userInfo(address).call()
```

the return is list like below

```
['0xf51334201581Fa539A73F75b16De43d32E66be19', 1642879683, 141130705699914691051, 66134241376982717881, 2483937465292180425, 1219485742680560672, 1642879683]
```

Now I need to call this function 15 times to retrieve information about all users upline and each time pass as the address result from previous function results, position 0 in the list above.

I've tried all the standard ways with

```
for i in range(10):
    get_upline(deposits[0])
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally figure out the answer to my questions. The problem is that variable was not available outside function so in the function in need to define the variable like this

```
claims_available = contract.functions.claimsAvailable(address).call()/1000000000000000000
deposits = contract.functions.userInfo(address).call()
custody = contract.functions.custody(address).call()
get_upline.variable = deposits // define the variable to be available outside function
```

And then create loop like this

```
for i in range(5):
    get_upline(get_upline.variable[0])
```